# NeoVim - Check if a Vim function exists from Lua

Tags: lua, neovim

I plan on using vim-plug with NeoVim. So, my `init.lua` file will have function calls such as

```
vim.fn['plug#begin'](vim.fn.stdpath('data') .. '/plugged')    
vim.fn['plug#']('hoob3rt/lualine.nvim')
```

However, I don't want to **assume** vim-plug is definitely installed. I want my `init.lua` file to degrade gracefully if vim-plug is not installed, rather than throwing an error

```
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: Vim:E117: Unknown function: plug#begin
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'plug#begin'
        /Users/andy/.config/nvim/init.lua:8: in main chunk
```

How can I check if the vim-plug functions exist **before** attempting to call them?

I tried `print(vim.fn['plug#begin'])` but that for some reason prints a non-null value: `function: 0x0104ba36f0`, even though the function doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried `print(vim.fn['plug#begin'])` but that for some reason prints a non-null value: `function: 0x0104ba36f0`, even though the function doesn't exist.

Presumably it's returning a function that throws the error you are getting. I would thus recommend using [`pcall`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-pcall):

```lua
local success, error = pcall(vim.fn['plug#begin'], vim.fn.stdpath('data') .. '/plugged')
if not success then --[[fail gracefully]] end
```

caveat: this will catch *any* error, so you'll probably want to perform some check like `if error:find"Unknown function" then ... end` to only catch this specific error.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. I'm using this for now. I requested a cleaner method in an issue: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/19271

Comment: why not use `:help exists()` ?

Comment: @JustinM.Keyes `exists()` actually won't work because vim-plug is autoloaded, so `exists()` will return false until you trigger something in NeoVim to look for the plugin and load it, such as calling `vim.fn['plug#begin']`. AFTER you do that, then `exists()`'s output will be accurate.

Answer (score 0):

```
let data_dir = has('nvim') ? stdpath('config') : '~/.vim'
if empty(glob(data_dir . '/autoload/plug.vim'))
  silent execute '!curl -fLo '.data_dir.'/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim'
  autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall --sync | source $MYVIMRC
endif
```